# How is R-squared calculated in the "Blavaan" R package and is it appropriate to use/report in bayesian analysis?

Tags: bayesian, r-squared

I am using the Blavaan R package to fit bayesian path analysis models. The output includes an R-squared value. It has come to my attention that there are problems with using R-squared for bayesian analysis i.e., it is a point estimate and can be greater than 1. I would like to know if Blavaan calculates it in a way that accounts for this.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I have heard of $R^2$ (or $R^2$-style) calculations yielding values below $0$ but never above $1$. What calculations have you seen that give values above $1?$

Comment: Thanks Dave, I am referring to this paper http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/bayes_R2_v3.pdf where they show that the fitted variance can be higher than the total variance resulting in a value greater than 1.

Comment: Which particular equation(s)?

Comment: they are referring to the classical R^2 formula

Comment: Please point to a particular equation. I can think of three ways that are reasonably described as the classical formula, and I want to discuss the one you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing any way to write formulas here, but the link above shows it on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late to answer, but blavaan does nothing special here. It feeds the posterior means to lavaan, which does the calculation as if it is a frequentist model. The code for lavaan's calculation is [on github.](https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/blob/a271f07a212fcf2902352833a37bde2202eb6b00/R/lav_object_inspect.R#L1368)